# How to take advantage of gnuplot internal functions by column reference at shell

Tags: variable, gnuplot

I want to do something like:

```
echo "p 'myfile.txt' u 1:(exp($2))" | gnuplot -p
```

but need the shell to pass the `$2` as a literal into gnuplot.

Answer (score 1):

Change your quoting around so that instead of double quotes (`"`) use single quotes (`'`) to wrap the entire argument to `echo` and use double quotes around the filename, like so:

```
$ echo 'p "myfile.txt" u 1:(exp($2))' | gnuplot -p
```

#### Example

Make some fake data:

```
$ for i in `seq 1 10`;do echo -e "$i\t$i";done > myfile.txt
```

Results in this:

```
1   1
2   2
3   3
4   4
5   5
6   6
7   7
8   8
9   9
10  10
```

Running the command, produces this graph:

```
$ echo 'p "myfile.txt" u 1:(exp($2))' | gnuplot -p
```

[image: ss of gnuplot graph]

#### References

- [Simple GNUPlot Commands](http://www.lukeabraham.com/ga/gnuplot.pdf)
- [Gnuplot Tutorial](http://physics.ucsc.edu/~medling/programming/gnuplot_tutorial_1/index.html)